# print an array of structs, C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I wanna print my array of structs but i keep getting segmentation fault,
what am i doing wrong? I start by using another function to read in data. Then i wanna be able to view what i just typed in.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max 100
#define min 30
struct vara{
    char namn[min];
    int saldo;
    int nummer;
};
struct vara varor[max];

int addvara(struct vara varor[], int length)
{
    int s, n = 1;
    //char nm;
    printf("Vill du scanna in vara? 1 för ja. 0 för att återgå till menyn\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n != 0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            printf("Namm, saldo, varunummer\n");
            scanf("%s", varor[i].namn);
            scanf("%d", &varor[i].saldo);
            scanf("%d", &varor[i].nummer);
            //struct vara invara = {"%s, %d, %d", nm, s, n};
            //varor[length] = invara;
            i=length;
            length++;
            printf("Vill du scanna in vara? 1 för ja. 0 för att återgå till menyn\n");
            scanf("%d", &n);
        }

    }
    return length;
}

void view(struct vara varor[], int length)
{
    printf("Varunummer \t\t Namn \t\t Varunummer\n");
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \t\t %d \t\t %d", varor[i].namn, varor[i].saldo, varor[i].nummer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't be diagnosed from this sample. Show us some actual running code.

Comment: The unconditional `i=length;` within the body of `for(int i=0; i<length; i++)` makes no sense. You then increment `length` so that's an infinite loop? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Your `addvara` is confusing, how do you increment `length`? You are most probably indexing the array out of bound which is undefined behaviour and a segaullt is the consequence.

Comment: "what am i doing wrong?"  Code is not checking the return values from `scanf()`.  example: `scanf("%s", varor[i].namn);` --> `if (scanf("%29s", varor[i].namn) != 1) Handle_Error();`. Like wise for the other `scanf()`.

Comment: hmm i see i need to change somethings i will post edited code soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the root of the problem is your `addvara` function, your loops don't make sense.

With `i=length;` you are overwriting the running index, then you do
`length++;`. If the user wishes to continue, you exit the `for` loop and enter it
again, depending on the number of times the user inputs the values, you are
going to eventually access `varor` out of bounds, which is undefined behaviour
and a segfault is a consequence of that.

I'd rewrite the `addvara` function like this:

```
// helper function to clean stdin
void clean_stdin()
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

// helper function to read in a loop until you get the value
// return 1 on success, 0 on failure, cannot continue reading
int read_from_stdin(const char *format, void *ptr, const char *prompt)
{
    int err;
    do {
        if(prompt)
        {
            printf("%s", prompt);
            fflush(stdout);
        }

        err = scanf(format, ptr);

        if(err == EOF)
            return 0;

        if(err != 1)
        {
            printf("Invalid value, try again\n");
            clean_stdin();
        }

    } while(err != 1);

    return 1;
}

int addvara(struct vara varor[], int length)
{

    if(varor == NULL)
        return -1; // error value

    if(length < 0)
        return -1;

    // helper to creata a format for scanf
    // %29[^\n]s, the number depends on sizeof varor[0].namn
    char strfmt[100];
    sprintf(strfmt, "%%%zu[^\n]s", sizeof(varor[0].namn) - 1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        int ask;

        if(read_from_stdin("%d", &ask, "Vill du scanna in vara? 1 för ja. 0 för att återgå till menyn\n") == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot continue reading\n");
            return i; // number of values added so far
        }

        if(ask == 0)
            return i; // the number of values added

        // otherwise scanf might complain about leftovers in the input buffer
        clean_stdin();


        if(read_from_stdin(strfmt, varor[i].namn, "Namm: ") == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot continue reading\n");
            return i; // number of values added so far
        }

        // otherwise scanf might complain about leftovers in the input buffer
        clean_stdin();

        if(read_from_stdin("%d", &varor[i].saldo, "Saldo: ") == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot continue reading\n");
            return i; // number of values added so far
        }

        if(read_from_stdin("%d", &varor[i].nummer, "Varunummer: ") == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot continue reading\n");
            return i; // number of values added so far
        }

        putchar('\n');
    }

    return i;
}
```

Your printing function looks OK. But you could improve how your format your
output, for example:

```
void view(struct vara varor[], int length)
{
    printf("%-30s %-10s %s\n", "Namn", "Saldo", "Nummer");

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        printf("%-30s %-10d %d\n", varor[i].namn, varor[i].saldo, varor[i].nummer);
}
```

The output would look like this

```
Namn                           Saldo      Nummer
Jan                            129        1113232
Maria                          232        44342234
```

**edit**

As [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076036/print-an-array-of-structs-c/49076844#comment85160979_49076844) pointed out in the comments, my `read_from_stdin` function has technically
undefined bevahiour, because `scanf` expects a `int*` pointer for the `%d`
format and I'm using a `void*` pointer.

I'd like to quote chux here:

> *chux wrote in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076036/print-an-array-of-structs-c/49076844#comment85164344_49076844)*
>
> `"%d"` expects a `int *`, not a `void *`. A `void *` and `int*` could be of different widths, encodings

However after 15 year of writing C code, I've never come across a commonly used architecture where this is the case and
a function like this would actually fail. Unless your target architecture isn't an exotic one, this function would work as I intended.

Comment: ok great thanks!! Im still going trough your code trying to understand everything. When im testing it out it seems to work fine except the output prints a lot of zeros. can print a screenshot tomorrow.

Comment: `void *ptr ... scanf(format, ptr);` is technical UB when `format` is `"%d"`, yet I am certain it will work as desired on all platforms you try.

Comment: @chux can you please elaborate more on why it is technically UB? Are there really platforms out there where this would fail?

Comment: `"%d"` expects a `int *`, not a `void *`.  A `void *` and `int*`  could be of different widths, encodings, etc. "Are there really platforms out there where this would fail? " I doubt it.

Comment: @chux thanks for the feedback, I've added a warning about my `read_from_stdin` function.